# animation happening before actually hovering element

Tags: css, sass

I have positioned a circle inside another element, in the centre of it and when I hover, a box-shadow should appear and it should move slightly. This works but for some reason when I refresh the page the circle moves from the bottom right corner very quickly to the centre. This movement is animated and only happens on page refresh. Why would this be?

```
 <div class="col-1-of-2">
      <div class="bg-video">
        <div class="bg-video__circle">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

.bg-video {
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba($color-primary, 0.8), rgba($color-secondary, 0.8)),  url(../img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 39rem;
    width: auto;

    &__circle {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
        width: 15rem;
        height: 15rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: $color-white;
        transition: box-shadow .4s, transform .4s;

        &:hover {

            box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(#000, .4);  
            transform: translate3d(-50%,-52%,0);
            cursor: pointer;

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the compiled css

```
.bg-video {
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.8), rgba(142, 68, 173, 0.8)), url(../img/hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 39rem;
  width: auto; }
  .bg-video__circle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    width: 15rem;
    height: 15rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: box-shadow .4s, transform .4s; }
    .bg-video__circle:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      transform: translate3d(-50%, -52%, 0);
      cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a `transition` on your `transform` that you have setting it to non 0,0 from the default state of the element. So when `&__circle` gets loaded on refresh it's animating to that transform from 0,0 to via the `translate3d(-50%,-50%,0)` because the transition: box-shadow .4s, **transform .4s**; is telling it to. It would be expected. Cheers!